# How can I execute a .bat before publish starts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dns

Hi I am looking for some guidance on this...

I want to change my dns settings before publishing... I made a bat that changes the dns but I have no Idea on how to execute it before publishing.

note that I want to execute it before publishing and not after build

thanks in advance.

... so there is no way to do this???...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this...

1. before publishing double click on the bat file
2. wait till its done
3. publish your project
4. dance arround the room